# How CSR signing works?

Tags: openssl, x509, csr

Im trying to sign a csr file in pem format using openssl API. The only problem is that I cant use X509_sign() method because I need to sign it using a third party API in which I need to send it the data to sign and it will return me the signature.

I asked before (still pending) how to load a .csr file using openssl API, when I figure out how to load it, I will send all the data from the file to sign, then, I will vreate an x509 object and set all the info from the csr as well the signature.

My question is, I need to send it the char* to sign to the 3rd party api but I dont know how the signing works, I mean... Do I need to construct this char* with only the data from the csr for example the subject, the exponent and modulus of the oublic key...

```
Char* = "DN=test,O=something...123456(this is the exponent)a2:43:65(this is the modulus)...
```

I mean, only the values... Or Do I need to build my buffer with all the certicate as appear with the -text command in openssl:

> Certificate:
>   Data:
>   Subject: dn=test, O=something
>   Public key info:
>   Exponent: 123456
>   Modulus:
>   A2:43:65
>   ....

Only to be clear, my question is, how work the x509 signing?? What data it takes?? Only the values or with the descriptions??or it takes all the .csr in pem format?

> --Begin signing request--
>   Tetw6561... Some base64 encrypted...727272 --end signing request--

I mean, the data in the csr file in pem format, as same as when you
create it with openssl (openssl      Req ...)???

Best regards

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: `DN=test...` - The distinguished name (`DN`) is a mashup of the `RDNs` like `O`, `OU`, `C`, etc. See [RFC 4514, Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP): String Representation of Distinguished Names](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt). RFC 4514 is one way to form a `DN`. There are other ways (i.e., different fields you can use).